# matplotlib read_png_int image has unknown bit depth

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code using matplotlib 3.2.1 that I previously wrote and worked fine.  I transferred it to another host with the same version and now I get an error mostly.  Every now and then it seems to work.

I am trying to read a png into an array:

```
import matplotlib._png as png
import requests
from io import BytesIO
url='https://tilecache.rainviewer.com/v2/radar/1625508000/512/6/35.71/-70.87/0/0_1.png'
im = png.read_png_int(BytesIO(requests.get(url).content))

RuntimeError: image has unknown bit depth
```

Note that this example URL currently works at the time of posting, but the 1625508000 timestamp component of the URL will expire at some point.  The request seems to be successful and I see the PNG data.

Comment: Matplotlib._png is private so end users should not be using it.

Comment: do you have an alternate recommendation on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I believe Pillow is how one reads images.  That is probably all `_read_png_int` does as well, but you might as well use the public interface.  Not at all sure that is what is causing your problem though

Comment: In pillow, I mainly see functions for reading Files.  I am receiving the file into memory.  Is there a function to open it directly without saving it out first?